# Apache POI: Find out colspan of text overflowing to next column

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm using Apache POI for converting Excel to HTML. I want the HTML table to be exactly as it appears in Excel. I see that many times there are cases where data in Excel cell overflows to next column. Is there a way to find out how many columns is the data spanning so I can add a `colspan` attribute to the `TD` tag? See this screenshot from Excel:

[image]

In this case, the data in cell A2 is overflowing to cell B2 (also A3 overflowing to B3). Is there a way to find out that the TD tag corresponding to cell A2 needs `colspan="2"` attribute?

The cells where the data is overflowing are not merged so I cannot really use functions like `sheet.getNumMergedRegions()`

I think I can also calculate it if somehow I can find out the "visible" width of columns in Excel. However, `sheet.getColumnWidth()` only provides the actual width. I don't see a method to find out the "visible" width of a column in Excel. In the screenshot link above the visible width of column A is very small. Is there a way to find that "visible" width?

I'm using Apache POI 3.17

Comment: How about calling `autoSizeColumn` before you read the column width, to force the columns to be wide enough for all their text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Apache poi` is able autosize the columns according to their contents. So it needs to be able calculating what column width a special content would need. This is what [SheetUtil.getCellWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/util/SheetUtil.html#getCellWidth-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell-int-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormatter-boolean-) is doing.

Additionally one needs to know the very special measurement units `Microsoft` has introduced for column widths in `Excel`. In `Excel`s `GUI` a column width of 10 for example means that 10 characters of default character width fits into the cell width. But internally the width is calculated in units of 1/256th of a default character width. That's why `apache poi` decided to get [Sheet.getColumnWidth](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#getColumnWidth-int-) in units of 1/256th of a character width.

So if you have got a `Cell cell` having cell index `c` and having a special content, then using

```
Workbook workbook...
...
DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
...
int defaultCharWidth = SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(workbook);
...
double cellValueWidth = SheetUtil.getCellWidth(cell, defaultCharWidth, dataFormatter, false);
int neededColunmnWidth = (int)cellValueWidth*256;
int columnWidth = sheet.getColumnWidth(c);
...
```

you could determine whether the content fits into the cell. It fits if `columnWidth >= neededColunmnWidth`, else it fits not and `colspan` must be used.

Lets have a complete example to show the principle:

Sheet:

[image]

Code:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.SheetUtil;

import java.io.*;

class ExcelToHTMLColspan {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("Test.xlsx"));

  DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

  int defaultCharWidth = SheetUtil.getDefaultCharWidth(workbook);

  int lastColumnToExport = 5; // column E

  Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  Row row;
  Cell cell;
  String cellValue;

  StringBuilder tableHTML = new StringBuilder();

  tableHTML.append("<TABLE>");
  tableHTML.append("<COLGROUP>");
  for (int c = 0; c < lastColumnToExport; c++) {
   long columnWidthPx = Math.round(sheet.getColumnWidthInPixels(c));
   tableHTML.append("<COL width=\"" + columnWidthPx + "\"/>");
  }
  tableHTML.append("</COLGROUP>");

  for (int r = 0; r <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
   row = sheet.getRow(r); if (row == null) row = sheet.createRow(r);
   long rowHeightPx = Math.round(row.getHeightInPoints() * 92f / 72f);
   tableHTML.append("<TR height=\"" + rowHeightPx + "\">");
   int c = 0;
   while(c < lastColumnToExport) {
    tableHTML.append("<TD");
    cell = row.getCell(c); if (cell == null) cell = row.createCell(c);
    cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
    double cellValueWidth = SheetUtil.getCellWidth(cell, defaultCharWidth, dataFormatter, false);
    int neededColunmnWidth = (int)cellValueWidth*256;
    int columnWidth = sheet.getColumnWidth(c);
    if (columnWidth < neededColunmnWidth) {
     int colSpan = 1;
     while(columnWidth < neededColunmnWidth) {
      colSpan++;
      c++;
      columnWidth += sheet.getColumnWidth(c);
     } 
     tableHTML.append(" colspan=\"" + colSpan + "\""  + ">" + cellValue);
     c++;
    } else {
     tableHTML.append(">" + cellValue);
     c++;
    }
    tableHTML.append("</TD>");
   }
   tableHTML.append("</TR>");
  }

  tableHTML.append("</TABLE>");

  workbook.close();

System.out.println(tableHTML.toString());

  //creating a sample HTML file 
  String encoding = "UTF-8";
  FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("result.html");
  OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fos, encoding);
  writer.write("<!DOCTYPE html>\n");
  writer.write("<html lang=\"en\">");
  writer.write("<head>");
  writer.write("<meta charset=\"utf-8\"/>");
  writer.write("<style>");
  writer.write("table {border-collapse: collapse; table-layout: fixed;}");
  writer.write("table, tr, td {border: 1px solid black;}");
  writer.write("td {font: 11pt Calibri, arial, sans-serif;}");
  writer.write("</style>");
  writer.write("</head>");
  writer.write("<body>");

  writer.write(tableHTML.toString());

  writer.write("</body>");
  writer.write("</html>");
  writer.close();

  java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new File("result.html").toURI());

 }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer. This helped me a lot.